Register flags abbreviations in Windbg
I used trace (t) command in Windbg but I don't see the flag values, except this:
nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
I suppose these are some abbreviations of flag states but I cannot find what they mean. Is there some reference of this?
Thanks in adv,
Adi

check x86 flags registers

in x86 the flag is denoted by EFLAGS
in x64 the flag is denoted by RFLAGS
Bit 0 is Carry Flag
CF  and can be either NC (No Carry) or CY (Carry)
Bit 1 is reserved Flag and is normally set to 1
Bit 2 is Parity Flag
PF and can be either PE (Parity EVEN) or PO (Parity Odd)
Bit 3 is reserved Flag
Bit 4 is Auxillary Carry
AF and can be either AC (Aux Carry) or NA (No Aux Carry)
Bit 5 is reserved Flag
Bit 6 is Zero Flag
ZF and can be either ZR (Zero) or NZ (Not Zero)
Bit 7 is Sign Flag
SF and can be either NG (Negative ) or PL (Positive)
Bit 8 is Trap Flag
TF and is used for single Step Trap
Bit 9 is Interrupt Enable
IF and can be either EI (Enable Interrupt) or DI (Disable Interrupt)
Bit 10 is Direction Flag
DF and can be either DN (DOWN ) or UP (UP)
Bit 11 is OverFlow Flag
OF and can be either OV (OverFlow ) or NV (No OverFlow)
Bit 12 & 13 is IOPL Flag
used for Privilege level  (user privileges and kernel privileges)
in windbg you can set the efl to 0 and check the register display as below
0:000> r efl =0
0:000> r
iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na pe nc
efl=00000000

since all bits are 0  the display shows
nc = No Carry
pe = Parity Even
na = No Auxillary Carry
nz = Not Zero
pl = Positive
di = Disable Interrupt
up = Direction Up
nv = No Overflow

and then set each flag individually to check the display
setting carry flag changes nc to cy
0:000> r cf =1
0:000> r
iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na pe cy

setting the parity flag changes pe to po
0:000> r pf =1
0:000> r
iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na po cy

and so on
0:000> r af =1
0:000> r zf =1
0:000> r sf =1
0:000> r tf =1
0:000> r if =1
0:000> r df =1
0:000> r of =1
0:000> r
iopl=0         ov dn ei ng zr ac po cy

for other esetoric flags check the link as commented or wikipedia here

Thank you very, very much! Your answer exceeds what I wanted to know :-)
